# Python name is not defined while converting json tweets to csv

Tags: python, json, twitter, nameerror

*Hello friends!
I want to convert my raw json tweets which i got using tweepy to csv and just two fields, "created at" and "text" in to ASCII 
I am having error which is NameError "data_python" is not defined.
I am confused.
Thank you in advance

here is my code

```
import json
import csv
try:
    data_json = open('nawaz.json', mode='r').read()
    data_python = json.loads(data_json) // here....
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

csv_out = open('tweets_out_ASCII.csv', mode='w')
writer = csv.writer(csv_out)

fields = ['created_at', 'text']
writer.writerow(fields)

for line in data_python:   // here it gives error
    writer.writerow([line.get('created_at'),   line.get('text').encode('unicode_escape'))]

csv_out.close()
```

here is the error i am recieving

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "json_to_csv.py", line 25, in <module>
    for line in data_python:
NameError: name 'data_python' is not defined
```

here is my json example

```
[![json example[![\]\[1\]][1]][1]
```

Comment: fix your indent. And have you imported json at all?

Comment: yes i already did

Comment: @AsifKhan Make sure the code you post reproduces the problem. See how to make a [mcve].

Comment: brother i have added my test result now

Comment: Your example is not JSON.

Comment: An exception while loading the json data makes so that the data_json isnt defined. Please provide json input. Catching exceptions like you are doing doesnt do anything useful

Answer (score 2):

When it throws the error, it jumps past assigning to the variable, as `data_json` is probably not valid json.

Consider this:

```
try:
    n = int('a')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

What would `n` be? It can't be assigned to everything, as the raised exception makes it skip past the assignment.

So, you can either give it a default value:

```
try:
    data_json = open('nawaz.json', mode='r').read()
    data_python = json.loads(data_json)
except Exception:
    data_python = []  # Some default value
```

Or you can just not catch the exception and let it fail.

Comment: "Or you can just not catch the exception and let it fail." excellent! why catching exceptions when you cannot handle them? I wouldn't have answered otherwise.